# I get a 404 not found when going to my site url, but content will show when navigation to url/craftfolder/web

Tags: craft4

I've made for the second time a craftCMS website. But is goes wrong at the deployment.
After many times of trying, I got it kinda working when going to siteurl/craftfolder/web.
In that case the content will load without styling.

but I want to load the content with styling at the siteurl, I have some htaccesses and all of that but nothing realy works..
Can anyone help me out..?

[image: This is my folder structure, where www is the root of the webserver]

In my rootfolder I have a site.conf file and an .htaccess

**site.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName jbjokido.be
    DocumentRoot "/www/jbjokido.be/web" 

    <Directory "/www/jbjokido.be/web">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    
</VirtualHost>
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^jbjokido.be$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.jbjokido.be$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !directory/
RewriteRule (.*) /directory/$1 [L]
```

Inside the web folder, where my index.php is, is also an .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^jokido/web(.*)$ $1 [L,NC]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I hope someone can figure it all out because I'm getting frustrated for not seeing it..

Comment: Have you defined the craft site URL in either your `.env` file or `general.php` config file?

Answer (score 1):

have you been able to solve this? I believe it is your folder structure. Craft CMS has some good [docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/directory-structure.html) on this.

Personally, when I host Craft sites the structure looks like this. *Please note your assets folder can be within your web folder or not, depending on how you have your file connecting in your admin/code.*

```
www
|– sitename.com
  |– .htaccess
  |– favicon.ico
  |– index.php (empty from Craft install)
  |– web.config
  |– /assets
    |–  /dist (containing CSS and JS)
    |– /fonts
    |– /images
  |– /cpresources
  |– /web
    |– .env
    |– composer.json
    |– craft
    |– /config
    |– /modules
    |– /path
    |– /storage
    |– /templates
    |– /vendor
```

My .htaccess files says the following in my root directory of the website

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
         RewriteEngine On

         # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
         RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
     </IfModule>
```

Let me know if this helps or if you have other questions.